# Cant run a selenium python script with crontab

Tags: python, selenium, cron

I have a python script that finds my grades in a webpage and sends me an email if any of my grades have been changed. Im now trying to run this script every hour with crontab.
The script works when running through terminal:

```
python3 /home/pi/Desktop/grades/script.py
```

In my script, I am trying to run crontab with `* * * * * python3 /home/pi/Desktop/grades/script.py`

I also added the shell to use: `SHELL=/bin/bash`

When the script is ran through the IDLE, it cannot find the crontab directory to schedule the scipt. I have the PATH variable set, and I searched about this and nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be couple of ways to handle this.
1. You must specify full path of python

```
* * * * * '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/grades/script.py'
```

2. You should put shebang line in your script, ref examples.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 or  #!/usr/bin/python3.
* * * * * /home/pi/Desktop/grades/script.py
```

Comment: Sorry for my very limited knowledge of this, but wasnt this the purpose of providing the PATH variable?

Comment: Also, I tried all of your recommendations in different combinations. Addings each of the shabangs, as well as providing the full path to python3. Still no result

Comment: If you add PATH in your crontab, that also should work. are you getting any error?? try creating a file and see if cron actually working.

Comment: In my original post it says that I have tried to add the PATH variable to the crontab. But even with that, and all of the suggestions youve given, it still does not work